# How to use DISTINCT ON in ARRAY_AGG()?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT p.id) AS price_ids,
       array_agg(p.name)        AS price_names
FROM items 
         LEFT JOIN prices p on p.item_id = id
         LEFT JOIN third_table t3 on third_table.item_id = id
WHERE id = 1;
```

When I `LEFT JOIN` the `third_table` all my prices are duplicated.

I'm using `DISTINCT` inside `ARRAY_AGG()` to get the ids without dups, but I want the names without dups aswell.

If I use `array_agg(DISTINCT p.name) AS price_names`, it will return distinct values based on the name, not the id.

I want to do something similar to `array_agg(DISTINCT ON (p.id) p.name) AS price_names`, but it is invalid.

How can I use `DISTINCT ON` inside `ARRAY_AGG()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate first, then join:

```
SELECT p.price_ids,
       p.price_names,
       t3.*
FROM items
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT pr.item_id, 
            array_agg(pr.id)    AS price_ids,
            array_agg(pr.name)  AS price_names
     FROM prices pr
     GROUP BY pr.item_id
  ) p on p.item_id = items.id
  LEFT JOIN third_table t3 on third_table.item_id = id
WHERE items.id = 1;
```

Using a lateral join might be faster if you only pick a single item:

```
SELECT p.price_ids,
       p.price_names,
       t3.*
FROM items
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
     SELECT array_agg(pr.id)    AS price_ids,
            array_agg(pr.name)  AS price_names
     FROM prices pr
     WHERE pr.item_id = items.id
  ) p on true
  LEFT JOIN third_table t3 on third_table.item_id = id
WHERE items.id = 1;
```

Comment: I ended up using the lateral join, thanks for the help.